# Unable to set THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL in a REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS process

Tags: c++, msdn

I'm writing a C++ video capture process for windows, using Visual Studio 2015 and I would like to set THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL priority for the Callback thread receiving video frames according to what described in 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms685100

Target machine OS is a Windows Server 2008 R2.

The whole process priority is set to REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS at process launch time.
When the callback thread starts I set the priority to THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL using SetThreadPriority function.

Dumping thread priority before and after SetThreadPriority invocation I can see it changes from 0 to 15.

But according to the msdn link reported above I would expect a 31 priority value, since the process class is REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS.

I also try to call SetThreadPriority passing a 31 constant value, instead of using THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL defined value, but still I get 15 reading back the thread priority value.

I can't understand which could be my error.

Comment: The user can very easily lose control over the machine when your thread(s) run with REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS.  So this is blocked, your program must acquire UAC elevation first.  Not 100% sure if that is enough.  Doesn't matter, this is just not appropriate for a media player.

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion.
Is there any way to acquire UAC elevation from source code ?
In addition I would add that I tried launching my application with admin privilege and I also tried to disable UAC notification: in both cases I'm still getting a 15 value reading back the priority set for my thread.