# How to increase process/thread priority more than 15 (high)

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, real-time, thread-priority

I have an Intel processor with 8 physical cores (16 with hyper-threading), and I am trying to fully utilize four of these cores by increasing the priority of my C++ application's process and the priority of four threads I am starting in this application (I am using OpenMp to lunch threads).

According to Microsoft's priority table:

| Process priority class | Thread priority level | Base priority |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS | THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE | 1 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST | 11 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL | 12 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL | 13 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL | 14 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST | 15 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL | 15 |
| REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS | THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE | 16 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST | 22 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_BELOW_NORMAL | 23 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL | 24 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL | 25 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST | 26 |
|  | THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL | 31 |

When I do the following, I only see priority set to 15:

```
int priority;
SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
SetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread(), THREAD_PRIORITY_TIME_CRITICAL);
priority = GetThreadPriority(GetCurrentThread());
```

Also, checking the priority from the Task Manager, it is set to high, not real-time.

How can I increase the priority to more than 15?

Comment: That said, you only raise priority if you are seeing your threads being preempted by another process. Is that your concern?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am trying to make sure my process CPU allocation is maximize

Comment: Note this warning from the docs: "You should almost never use `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`, because this interrupts system threads that manage mouse input, keyboard input, and background disk flushing. This class can be appropriate for applications that "talk" directly to hardware or that perform brief tasks that should have limited interruptions."

Comment: For your actual question: 1. You don't check whether the `SetPriority` calls actually succeed. 2. Base priority is not thread priority. The thread priority always maxes out at 15. The base priority is computed from the class and thread priority

Comment: @Homer512, I read that, but on my machine I have 8 cores and reserving 4 of them will leave 4 cores to other processes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198564/unable-to-set-thread-priority-time-critical-in-a-realtime-priority-class-process

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a default windows installation you need to have Administrator-Privileges to increase the priority class of a process to `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`.

The privilege you need to have for this is called [`SE_INC_BASE_PRIORITY_NAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/privilege-constants#se_inc_base_priority_name):

> | Contant/value | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | **SE_INC_BASE_PRIORITY_NAME** TEXT("SeIncreaseBasePriorityPrivilege") | Required to increase the base priority of a process. User Right: Increase scheduling priority. |

By default this privilege is only given to members of the Administrator Group,
but you can use the [Increase scheduling priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/increase-scheduling-priority) group policy to also grant normal users this privilege.

---

Assuming you're running as a user that has access to said privilege (by default only members of the Administrators Group), and the privilege is [enabled for the current process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/enabling-and-disabling-privileges-in-c--), then you should be able to increase your processes priority to realtime with:

```cpp
SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(), REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
```

---

#### Why Realtime Priority is usually a bad idea

Keep in mind though that realtime priority does really mean realtime.

Almost all system processes run at a lower priority than realtime - so if your process decides to do some heavy computations it'll completely block the rest of your system from doing anything.

> [Scheduling Priorities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/scheduling-priorities#priority-class)
> Use `HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS` with care. If a thread runs at the highest priority level for extended periods, other threads in the system will not get processor time. **The high-priority class should be reserved for threads that must respond to time-critical events.**
> [...]
> The important point is that a high-priority thread should execute for a brief time, and only when it has time-critical work to perform.
>
> **You should almost never use `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`, because this interrupts system threads that manage mouse input, keyboard input, and background disk flushing.** This class can be appropriate for applications that "talk" directly to hardware or that perform brief tasks that should have limited interruptions.

Recommended read: [When you set a 100% CPU program to real-time priority, you get what you asked for](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100610-00/?p=13753)

For almost all tasks its usually best to leave the priority at its default (`NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS` - `THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL`) - you'll still get plenty of cpu time, but you don't starve out any other applications that also need some.

- If you have an application that is truly time critical you can **temporarily** increase your priority to high.
- realtime priority should only ever be used if you're actually talking to a hardware device that requires precise timing.

Comment: If I set the priority to real time and have 8 cores on my machine, why that would block the rest of your system from doing anything? all other processes will have 7 cores to run on.

Comment: @Anas as long as you only actually have 1 thread running in your process you'll probably be fine, that's true. But keep in mind that by setting the process priority class to `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS` will automatically increase the priority of all threads in that process to a base priority of at least 16 (i.e. realtime), and there's no way to lower individual threads to non-realtime. That also means the winapi threadpool in your process will also run at realtime, as well as any other threads you directly (or indirectly) create within your program.

Comment: What i'm trying to say is that *for most usecases* realtime priority is overkill; if you still want to go for it then all you need to do is run your program as an Administrator (or use the group policy). Then your program should run at realtime priority :)

Comment: Thanks, I will try running as an administrator.

Comment: *"And then he shoots himself in the foot and asks to be coddled a little bit."*

Comment: @Anas BTW: You might have threads on your system that are bound to specific CPUs and cannot move out of the way. They will simply starve. At least ramp up from regular priorities and see if it brings any benefits before going straight for the "break the system" settings that everybody *including the guy who wrote the system* warns you about

Comment: When reading the `thread priority` value back. Do you read `15` or `31`? I read `15`, but I also read the class as `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS.` So, I am quite confused with the `31` value.

Comment: @EduardoReis if you get a base priority of 15 then your priority class cannot be `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS`. The process priority is combined with the thread priority to form the base priority of your thread. ([see here for a neat table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/scheduling-priorities#base-priority)). The lowest base priority you can get within `REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS` is 16 (by setting the thread priority to `THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE`). 15 is only possible in lower priority classes.

Comment: @Turtlefight, I understand the `31`. What is quite confusing to me is the reason why I am getting the right priority class but not the thread priority. Specifically, why would one work and not the other? When inspecting the process with the task monitor, I see real-time priority. I have set my application to run with Admin privileges, which is confirmed within the code. Do you have any tips on how I could try to get the `31` priority thread?